# Lotus Notes 8.5: Button not working when document in preview pane?

Tags: command, preview, execute, lotus

I try to set up some email workflows (voting, sign up, and so on) with Notes 8.5. 
Everything seems OK but I can't figure out how to get my functions work from the email preview pane!?

For Example:

```
@If(@IsDocBeingEdited;
@PostedCommand([FileSave]);
@Do(    @PostedCommand([EditDocument]);
        @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
      @PostedCommand([EditDocument])))
```

This code (on a button) works fine when I open the email by double clicking it but if I click the same button in the preview I get this: "cannot execute specified command"

Is there any way to get my commands work from the preview pane? Most (all?) useres view/read ther mails in preview mode so they would also interact with forms and buttons from there...!

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes shows document in preview pane only with read mode. But your code need edit mode of document. You should add

```
@Command([OpenDocument];@False; @DocumentUniqueID);
```

instead first `@PostedCommand([EditDocument]);`

Comment: Better but still get the error message... actual cide:
´@If(disablebutton="1";
    @Return(@Prompt([Ok];"Fehler";"Danke, deine Antwort wurde bereits registriert"));
    @Prompt([Ok];"Danke";"Vielen Dank für deine Antwort"));
@MailSend( "heinz.haim@ams.at"; ""; "" ; "Ich nehme teil!" ;
            @Name([CN];@UserName); "1234567" ; [PriorityNormal] );
FIELD disablebutton:="1";
@If(@IsDocBeingEdited;
    @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
    @Do(    @Command([OpenDocument];@False; @DocumentUniqueID);
            @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
          @PostedCommand([CloseDocument])))